# PHP ternary operator

Tags: php, html

I have 2 ternary operator as below:

```
1. (($_POST['movietype'] == $row1['id'])?'selected="selected"':'');
2. (($row1['id'] == $row['type'])?'selected="selected"':'');
```

Below are my output:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row1['id'].'"'.[HERE].'>'.$row1['label'].'</option>';
```

My question is how do I combine these 2 ternary operator into [HERE] section?

Comment: **Don't**. If I saw combined ternary operators in HTML I'd find the developer who wrote that and smack them. *Hard*. Write that code is as many lines as you need for *it to be readable* and then put that resulting output in your HTML.

Comment: That mean use if...else statement or switch statement to write the above code?

Comment: Yes. One-liners are always nice but never use them at the expense of making the code harder to read and maintain. You'll thank yourself later. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

It's just 2 conditions for the same thing that you can even combine in one condition if you use `in_array()`.

So something like:

```
$class = ($_POST['movietype'] == $row1['id'] || $row1['id'] == $row['type'])
            ? 'class="selected"' : '';
```

or:

```
$class = in_array($row1['id'], array($_POST['movietype'], $row1['id']))
            ? 'class="selected"' : '';
```

and:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row1['id'].'" '.$class.'>'.$row1['label'].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your same code, you can do something like this:

```
    $isSelected = ($_POST['movietype'] == $row1['id'] || $row1['id'] == $row['type']) 
                   ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
```

Then you can replace the `[HERE]` section as the following:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row1['id'].'" '.$isSelected.'>'.$row1['label'].'</option>';
```

By the way, i recommend you to use `If...Else`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a function that you can pass a unlimited # of values to that could trigger the option to be selected

```
/**
* @param id
* @param matches...
**/
function selectOpt() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $id = array_shift($args);
    foreach($args as $a) {
        if($a === $id) {
            return 'selected="selected"';
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row1['id'].'"'. selectOpt($row1['id'], $_POST['movietype'], $row['type']) .'>'.$row1['label'].'</option>';
```